# When I put an arrow next to a table I get an error

Tags: tables, errors, packages

I have a table and I would like to have an arrow on the right, but I get this error "Extra \right. $\right\Uparrow". How do I fix it? I use tikz package and graphicx.
Here's the code:

```
\begin{center}
$\right\Uparrow$    
        \begin{tabular}{ r|c } 
            42588 & 0 \\ 
            21294 & 0 \\
            10647 & 1 \\
            5323 & 1 \\
            2661 & 1 \\
            1330 & 0 \\
            665 & 1 \\
            332 & 0 \\
            166 & 0 \\
            83 & 1 \\
            41 & 1 \\
            20 & 0 \\
            10 & 0 \\
            5 & 1 \\
            2 & 0 \\
            1 & 1 \\
            0 & - \\
        \end{tabular}
$\right\Uparrow$        
\end{center}
```

Edit: this is what I would like to get as an output[image]

Edit 2:
I fixed it

```
\begin{center}
    $\left.
        \begin{tabular}{ r|c } 
            42588 & 0 \\ 
            21294 & 0 \\
            10647 & 1 \\
            5323 & 1 \\
            2661 & 1 \\
            1330 & 0 \\
            665 & 1 \\
            332 & 0 \\
            166 & 0 \\
            83 & 1 \\
            41 & 1 \\
            20 & 0 \\
            10 & 0 \\
            5 & 1 \\
            2 & 0 \\
            1 & 1 \\
            0 & - \\
        \end{tabular}
    \right\uparrow$     
\end{center}
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the table. Your arrow syntax is not correct.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: Is `$\Rightarrow$` what you need?

Comment: What output are you trying to get?  Normally, it's `\left ... \right`, but you're not allowed to leave math mode, and the left/right only works on somethings.

Comment: I don't know, this is literally the first time I'm using latex. All I know is that I have this table on the center and I want an arrow going up from the last number to the first one

Answer (score 4):

The idea of left/right is that you'll have `\left(left thing)(middle stuff)\right(right thing)`.  So your first problem is that you have two rights and no left.  Your next problem is that you leave math mode to have the tabular, and then reenter math mode, so that the `\left/\right` are in different groups.

You can get everything into one group by having it all in math mode and using `array` instead of `tabular`.  And since you don't want anything on the left, you can use `\left.` (note the period) to suppress that.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\left.
        \begin{array}{ r|c } 
            42588 & 0 \\ 
            21294 & 0 \\
            10647 & 1 \\
            5323 & 1 \\
            2661 & 1 \\
            1330 & 0 \\
            665 & 1 \\
            332 & 0 \\
            166 & 0 \\
            83 & 1 \\
            41 & 1 \\
            20 & 0 \\
            10 & 0 \\
            5 & 1 \\
            2 & 0 \\
            1 & 1 \\
            0 & - \\
        \end{array}
\right\Uparrow
\]
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: table of numbers with double up arrow]

If you want the single lined arrow of your picture, then you can use `\uparrow` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand